# Cannot find "Site Collection Storage Management" in SharePoint Online 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, quota

Our Microsoft TAM has told us of a recently deployed feature in SPO that allows all sites to shared a single pool of automatically managed storage. However the section of the admin panel he is telling me to use (named above) does not appear for me at all. [This MS blog post](http://blogs.office.com/2014/08/18/sharepoint-online-simplifies-storage-management/) also explains how to turn this feature on. The section highlighted simply is not there in my admin panel. I asked him for more information and here is his response (exact quote, except for the delinkifying the urls):

> Enable self service http: office.com/getoffice365 and
>   http: office.com/teachers will add an additional 750TB of pooled
>   SharePoint Online storage.

I am thinking he skipped a couple of indefinite articles in that sentence. He seems to be telling me to permission my farm to allow users to create their own sites (which I already do), then go to *two* sites (both of which redirect to the *same* SPO login page), and then my 750TB will automagically appear. I have spent the last hour crawling through all the Site Features, Site Collection Features, and anything else I could think of. I still cannot figure out what he is telling me.

Coming to this community in hopes of avoiding humiliating myself front of my TAM. Please save me from this terrible fate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "SharePoint Online storage usage model" is still rolling out as of 2015-01-31. Many tenants still do not have this feature deployed so likely that is why you are not seeing it in your tenant. Roadmap status for the storage usage model (http://roadmap.office.com/en-us#R-144-5167) is under the category "Rolling out".

Furthermore, only yesterday (30th Jan) on the Yammer Office 365 technical network, a Microsoft senior product manager confirmed the feature is still in roll out and likely completed in the next 1-2 weeks. https://www.yammer.com/itpronetwork/#/Threads/show?threadId=482239638

Comment: I KNEW IT! Lousy Microsoft interdepartmental non-communication. Thanks for helping me out with that Yammer link. Regarding TAM humiliation, it now seems the hand is on the other foot. ;)